# four columns adapter android studio with SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, listadapter

Good morning everyone,
I'm working on coding an adapter for my database that has 3 tables:
User, Question, Answer
An user is answering some questions generated from the DB and insert the answer 
I tried my SQLite code on SQLite browser and it worked perfectly, same as my SQL query.

I created a class History that contains the name, date, question and answer.
Then I created an activity_history that contains a ListView, and also an activity_adapter that has the 4 textViews, the class adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<history> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflat;
    private ArrayList<history> hist;
    private int mVRessId;


    public MyAdapter (Context context, int ressId, ArrayList<history> hists){

        super(context,ressId,hists);
        this.hist =hist;
        mInflat = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mVRessId =ressId;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertedView, ViewGroup parents){
        convertedView = mInflat.inflate(mVRessId,null);
        History histor = hist.get(position);



        if (histor != null){
            TextView name = (TextView) convertedView.findViewById(R.id.hname);
            TextView quest = (TextView) convertedView.findViewById(R.id.hques);
            TextView ans = (TextView) convertedView.findViewById(R.id.hans);
            TextView date = (TextView) convertedView.findViewById(R.id.hdate);

            if (name != null){
                name.setText(histor.getNom());
            }
            if (quest != null){
                quest.setText(histor.getQuest());
            }
            if (ans != null){
                name.setText(histor.getRep());
            }
            if (date != null){
                name.setText(histor.getDate().toString());
            }
        }
        return convertedView;
    }
}
```

In the DatabaseHelper, I made a function returning a Cursor using my SQL query:

```
 public Cursor getTableHistoAsCursor() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(" SELECT Q." + KEY_QUESTION + " , U." + KEY_NOM + " , U." + KEY_PRENOM + " , A." + KEY_DATE + " , A. " + KEY_REPONSE + " from " + TABLE_QUESTION + " Q, " + TABLE_USER + " U, " + TABLE_ANSWER + " A WHERE Q." + KEY_ID_QUESTION + " = A." + KEY_ID_QUESTION + " AND A." + KEY_MATRICULE + " = U." + KEY_MATRICULE, null);
        return data;
    }
```

The history class, I wrote this code:

```
public class Historian extends AppCompatActivity {

    ModelHelper openhelper; //<<<< Note 1
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor mCsr;
    ListView mListView;
    ArrayList<Historique> histList;
    Historique histo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_historique);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsthisto); //<<<< Note 3
        openhelper =  new ModelHelper(this);
        db = openhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        histList = new ArrayList<>();


        mCsr = openhelper.getTableHistoAsCursor();
        int rows = mCsr.getCount();
        if (rows == 0 ){
            Toast.makeText(Historian.this, "No histo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            while (mCsr.moveToNext()){

                histo = new Historique(mCsr.getString(0),mCsr.getString(1), mCsr.getString(2),mCsr.getString(3));
                histList.add(histo);
            }

            MyAdapter adapter =  new MyAdapter (this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout,histList);

        }
```

The problem is that when I execute, there is no problem or error compiling, just the listview is always empty.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that when I execute, there is no problem or error
>   compiling, just the listview is always empty.

You miss to setAdapter to the listView . Add `mListView .setAdapter(adapter);` after below line

`MyAdapter adapter =  new MyAdapter (this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout,histList);`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference

I got this problem, it's coming from the adapter

Comment: Historique histor = hist.get(position);
This is the line 34

Comment: why you need  `Historyhistor = hist.get(position);`?

Comment: to get the content, and use it after:
I created a variable type History that I can use getters from the class ...

Comment: is class `history` or `History`?  Please edit your post

Comment: The class is History.

Comment: I found the problem was the s in this.hists=hist;
still have some little problems but anyway I have the question that's showing. Thanks